# FormatException on DevExpress' TextEdit control that can't store my decimal value

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, decimal, textedit

I have a DevExpress (I will refer to it as "DX" for this question) control, the `TextEdit`.

Here a sample of what I have

```xml
<Grid>
    <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="te" MaskType="Numeric" Mask="###,##0.###"
                  MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" Validate="te_Validate"
                  Text="{Binding myValeur, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

The Mask `Mask="###,##0.###"` is normal, I'm limited to 9 numbers with 3 decimals.

I do this in my codebehind

```csharp
decimal myDecimalValue = 0.0m;
private void te_Validate(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Thread Thread_te_Validate = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(te.Text))
                myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text);
        }));
    });
    Thread_te_Validate.IsBackground = true;
    Thread_te_Validate.Start();
}
```

This code works with a strange problem. If I write `100` in my TextEdit, the value is correctly converted. If I write `100.123` (so I put some decimals), the application crashes with the error `FormatException was unhandled by user code` *(french traduction)*.

In details, I have `{"The format of the input string is incorrect."}`

The value of the TextEdit.Text at the crash is good `100.123` but the decimal only store `100` .

I'm french and use french culture so the 'comma' is the decimal separator for the UI but the variables are stored correctly with a 'point' in decimal separator.

**Edit :**
I test this code and the same error is going. So I think the problem is the conversion to decimal.
The `string` get the value with decimals but the conversion bug.

```csharp
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(te.Text))
{ 
    string test1 = te.Text;
    myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(test1);
}
```

**Edit 2 :**
This code don't woks too.

```csharp
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(te.Text))
{ 
    string test1 = te.Text;
    myDecimalValue = decimal.Parse(test1);
}
```

**Edit 3 :**
I also tried forcing culture during the conversion.
With this code, I can not insert a decimal in my TextEdit, only integers.

```csharp
myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

My **specific** culture send the `FormatException` error.

```
myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
```

My **neutral** culture send the `FormatException` error too.

```
myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr"));
```

**Solution working for me :**
This code works for me. I define my Langage at 'fr' in App.xaml but apparently, it's not suffisent. So the problem is really the Culture and of course, the decimal character.

For me, I need to replace the 'dot' with a 'comma' because the culture in DevExpress show me the good culture but store in US culture.

```csharp
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDXTextEdit.Text))
    myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(myDXTextEdit.Text.Replace(".", ","));
```

Comment: I have had issues with the `TextEdit.Text` property. Have you tried with the `EditValue` property instead?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but same result.
Values are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WPF uses `en-US` as the culture, regardless of the system settings. I believe you have not override this behavior, and moreover you've included the 'dot' as a decimal separator in the TextEdit.Mask. So far so good. That because you have received `100.23`(with 'dot' decimal separator) as a value. However the decimal conversion uses your current culture (which is `French`) as `IFormatProvider` thus you can not convert the text  into decimal value using this culture (that is the reason of the exception).

To avoid the exception, please specify the correct culture for conversion (you can use the InvariantCulture instead of `en-US`):

```
myDecimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(te.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks DmitryG but I've test it and don't work. I can't write decimal value in the TextEdit if the `InvarientCulture` is set.
I'll test to modify the Mask of the TextEdit to try.

Comment: Thanks for "orientation" of my problem, the cause is Culture

Comment: @Saesee I'm happy to hear that the problem is resolved. Could you update your question with the final solution?

Comment: I added it. I hope this can help other.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, it turned out that there were two problems.

First, the Binding of TextEdit were made on variables modified by TextEdit which created strange loops and bug to enter decimal.

Second, even if my application is defined in French culture, it must still force `String.Replace (".", "")` In order to properly perform the conversions.